# Auto Hot Key script to Copy data from a Doc file and Email it with an app or chrome Browser

Tags: autohotkey

I have some text in a .DOC File Which is stored on Desktop. Is this possible When

If I press CTRL+Q Then, Text inside that file gets copied
And email it via any app or Mail app that is included in window10 to the person that are shown in the picture. [How I want to email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiOY9.png)

***> You can also help me out, as I have the url of the email, I just have

> to reply there after opening the mail url and click send button.***

Comment: What do you plan on using this for?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the file content as text, you can then piece together a `mailto:` URI. By the [RFC 6068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6068) spec, a parser should accept the primary email, subject and body - the other fields (such as CC addresses) are up to the parser to implement.

Here's a quick script I threw together from snippets I've found.

```
#SingleInstance Force

EmailRecipient := "target@example.com"
EmailCC := ["target2@example.com", "target3@example.com"]
EmailSubject := "MY WORK PROGRESS"

^Q::
; Step 1) Gets filepath of first file
FirstFilePath := getFirstSelected()

; Step 2) Makes sure its a DOC or DOCX file
if (!(SubStr(FirstFilePath, -3) = ".doc" || SubStr(FirstFilePath, -4) = ".docx")) {
  MsgBox 0x1010, Doc Mailer, % "Not a doc/docx file!"
  return
}

; Learning one
; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/73386-fileread-word-docx-com-l-line-40-error/?p=494436
; Step 3) Opens it as a COM Object and copies its text content to the clipboard
oDoc := ComObjGet(FirstFilePath)
oDoc.Range.FormattedText.Copy  ; OR oDoc.Range.Text.Copy
oDoc.Close(0)

; Step 4) Takes the content on the clipboard and URI encodes it
encodedBody:=UriEncode(clipboard)

; Step 5) Build GET query string parts
params := []
if (EmailCC && EmailCC.Length()) {
  params.Push("cc=" . UriEncode(StrJoin(EmailCC, ",")))
}
if (EmailSubject) {
  params.Push("subject=" . UriEncode(EmailSubject))
}
if (encodedBody) {
  params.Push("body=" . encodedBody)
}
paramsStr := StrJoin(params, "&")

; Step 6) Build the mailto: URI
;MsgBox % "mailto:" . EmailRecipient . (paramsStr ? "?" . paramsStr : "")
Run, % "mailto:" . EmailRecipient . (paramsStr ? "?" . paramsStr : "")

return

; ---------------------

; Modified from Masonjar13's function
; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=154791#p154791
getFirstSelected(){
    cO:=clipboardAll
    clipboard:=
    send ^c
    clipWait
    selected:=clipboard
    clipboard:=cO
    return StrSplit(selected, "`r`n")[1]
}

; ---------------------

; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/75390-ahk-l-unicode-uri-encode-url-encode-function/?p=480216
; modified from jackieku's code (http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-310959.html#310959)
UriEncode(Uri, Enc = "UTF-8")
{
    StrPutVar(Uri, Var, Enc)
    f := A_FormatInteger
    SetFormat, IntegerFast, H
    Loop
    {
        Code := NumGet(Var, A_Index - 1, "UChar")
        If (!Code)
            Break
        If (Code >= 0x30 && Code <= 0x39 ; 0-9
            || Code >= 0x41 && Code <= 0x5A ; A-Z
            || Code >= 0x61 && Code <= 0x7A) ; a-z
            Res .= Chr(Code)
        Else
            Res .= "%" . SubStr(Code + 0x100, -1)
    }
    SetFormat, IntegerFast, %f%
    Return, Res
}

UriDecode(Uri, Enc = "UTF-8")
{
    Pos := 1
    Loop
    {
        Pos := RegExMatch(Uri, "i)(?:%[\da-f]{2})+", Code, Pos++)
        If (Pos = 0)
            Break
        VarSetCapacity(Var, StrLen(Code) // 3, 0)
        StringTrimLeft, Code, Code, 1
        Loop, Parse, Code, `%
            NumPut("0x" . A_LoopField, Var, A_Index - 1, "UChar")
        StringReplace, Uri, Uri, `%%Code%, % StrGet(&Var, Enc), All
    }
    Return, Uri
}

StrPutVar(Str, ByRef Var, Enc = "")
{
    Len := StrPut(Str, Enc) * (Enc = "UTF-16" || Enc = "CP1200" ? 2 : 1)
    VarSetCapacity(Var, Len, 0)
    Return, StrPut(Str, &Var, Enc)
}

; ---------------------

StrJoin(arr, delim = ",") {
  ret := ""
  Loop % arr.Length()
    ret := ret . (A_Index = 1 ? "" : delim) . arr[A_Index]
  return ret
}
```